# reading from text file

Tags: java

I'm writing a program which reads only integers from a text file. I have done the lions share of the program, however one thing is bothering me

When a non integer is in the text file, all the correct integers should be printed, with element not valid, replacing the element which is not valid. 
For example 10, 203, 2.02 10 would print 10, 203, element not valid 10 .
For this do i use an array to access the part which is not valid?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You display an error message to the user.

Comment: `System.out.println("You have entered either too few or not enough command-line arguments");`

Comment: nope not what im looking for...Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of arguments is 2, here is how would you do it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: ...");
        }
    }
```